# How to skin a canvas with an image and scale it to size of canvas in Flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, canvas, background-image

I'm trying to skin a canvas with an image (which is essentially a custom border for the canvas).  I've been trying the backgroundImage style as well as the borderSkin style.  I can't get the image to scale to the full size of the canvas though.  I was wondering what the best way to go about this is.

Basically I've been trying this:

```
<mx:Canvas id="canvas1" backgroundImage="../src/assets/custom_border.jpg" backgroundSize="100%"> CANVAS CONTENT </mx:Canvas>
```

What's the best way to scale the backgroundImage to the canvas size or is there a better way to go about this such as borderSkin or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably achieve what you're after using [Degrafa CSS skinning](http://blog.benstucki.net/?p=46). If not, you'll need to create a simple custom skin component.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to achieve.

If you are trying to get a really complex border then an image might be the most reasonable way to do check the 9 Slice Scaling in the link below.
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/embed_4.html#186094

Alternatively, if the boarder is relatively simple, you can override the updateDisplayList function and draw the style you want manually:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=skinstyle_3.html